# If statements with Find

Tags: vba, excel

I am adding information to a database. While doing so, I want to check if that information already exists in the database so I do not double write it.

```
Private Sub changebutton_dp_Click()
Dim sheet As Worksheet
Dim table_list_obj As ListObject
Dim table_obj_row As ListRow
Set sheet = Sheets("Database")
Set table_list_obj = sheet.ListObjects(1)
Set table_obj_row = table_list_obj.ListRows.Add

For Each sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Database")
   sheet.Cells.Find What:=DatabasePage.termaccepted_dp.Value,_
   LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole 
   If sheet.Cells.Find.Range Is Nothing Then
       DatabasePage.yesno_dp.Caption = No
   ElseIf IsEmpty(sheet.Cells.Find.Range) Then
       DatabasePage.yesno_dp.Caption = No
   ElseIf sheet.Cells.Find.Range = "" Then
       DatabasePage.yesno_dp.Caption = No
   Else
       DatabasePage.yesno_dp.Caption = Yes
       DatabasePage.display_dp.Value = sheet.Cells.Find.Value
   End If
Next sheet

table_obj_row.Range(1, 1).Value = DatabasePage.termdenied_dp.Value

last_row = sheet.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
last_row = last_row

sheet.Range("B" & last_row) = DatabasePage.termaccepted_dp.Value

End Sub
```

This gives several flags.

Comment: Please specify the lines at which you get flags; that is most helpful to readers.  For one I see several = No, which should in all probability be = "No", and your use of sheet.Cells.Find.Range is not allowed (see the documentation for .Find; press F1 on it in the VBA editor)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see, the only real issue is in your `For each worksheet` loop. Your code has some incorrect syntax and you have superfluous `ElseIf` conditions.

See the code below. *Note - I am taking a chance that `DatabasePage` stuff is correct, since I don't know exactly what it is at this point.*

```
For Each sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets 'assuming you want to loop through all sheets

    Dim rng As Range

    Set rng = sheet.Cells.Find(What:=DatabasePage.termaccepted_dp.Value, _
        LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)

    If rng Is Nothing Then
        DatabasePage.yesno_dp.Caption = No
    Else
        DatabasePage.yesno_dp.Caption = Yes
        DatabasePage.display_dp.Value = rng.Value
    End If

Next sheet
```

This code stores the value of the `Find` operation into a Range object and then tests if the object has a value or is Null.

Answer (score 0):

I can't test this, but you can't loop through the sheets in one sheet, and you need to store the result of the `Find` operation in a `Range` variable:

```
Private Sub changebutton_dp_Click()
    Dim sheet                 As Worksheet
    Dim table_list_obj        As ListObject
    Dim table_obj_row         As ListRow
    Dim rgFound               As Range

    Set sheet = Sheets("Database")

    Set table_list_obj = sheet.ListObjects(1)
    Set table_obj_row = table_list_obj.ListRows.Add

    Set rgFound = sheet.Cells.Find(What:=DatabasePage.termaccepted_dp.Value, _
                                   LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    If rgFound Is Nothing Then
        DatabasePage.yesno_dp.Caption = No
    ElseIf Len(rgFound.Value) = 0 Then
        DatabasePage.yesno_dp.Caption = No
    Else
        DatabasePage.yesno_dp.Caption = Yes
        DatabasePage.display_dp.Value = rgFound.Value
    End If


    table_obj_row.Range(1, 1).Value = DatabasePage.termdenied_dp.Value

    last_row = sheet.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row

    sheet.Range("B" & last_row) = DatabasePage.termaccepted_dp.Value

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! Helped a lot.